# Different function on click after preventing default

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, preventdefault

Test site here has a mobile menu (800px wide or less) that did not have drop down folder functionality.  I want the mobile nav menu to function like it does on desktop.

https://josh-unger-4lts.squarespace.com

The default of the title folder was to open up the first link in its folder so I prevent with:

```
<script>  

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mobileNav .mobile-folder>a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

 });
 });
 </script>
```

I want to instead display the hidden page links inside the "folder titles " on click.

My code here doesn't work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mobileNav .mobile-folder>a").click(function(){
$(this).find('.folder.external-link ul ').toggleClass("expand");
});
 });
  </script>
```

My CSS to hide page links and later display on toggle:

```
.folder.external-link {display:none!important;}


.folder.external-link.expand {display:block!important;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` is not a **child** element of `a` but a **sibling**

[image]

so your code should be like this (and you can also keep the `preventDefault()` ):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mobileNav .mobile-folder>a").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).siblings('ul ').toggleClass("expand");
    });
});
</script>
```

And your CSS should target the ul class :

```
.mobile-folder ul {display:none!important;}


.mobile-folder ul.expand {display:block!important;}
```

Comment: I swapped out to your code.  It look like the prevent default is not working now.  The first link in the folder now opens up.  @Temani Afif

Comment: @junger my bad ! copy/paste error, check again now :)

Comment: I separated out prevent to my original script and kept the rest of your code  and it seems to be working! Thanks so much @temani Aifif